# ошибка python: can't open file 'C:\Users\LATITUDE\Desktop\╨Ю╤Б╨╜╨╛╨▓\todo\manage.pyrunserver'[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

Сегодня запускала команду python manage.py runserver, но выходит ошибка

```
can't open file 'C:\Users\LATITUDE\Desktop\╨Ю╤Б╨╜╨╛╨▓╤Л ╨┐╤А╨╛╨│╤А╨░╨╝╨╝╨╕╤А╨╛╨▓╨░╨╜╨╕╤П\todo\manage.pyrunserver': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Использую Visual Studio Code, вчера устанавливала гит, возможно я сама удалила директорию. Заходила в Панель управления->система и безопасность->система-> переменные среды и там надо было прописать путь для гита. Как устранить ошибку?

Comment: Возможно в пути к вашему файлу присутствуют русские символы, попробуйте сделать путь исключительно с англ. буквами

Comment: Я только что создал папку *Основы программирования* (назвал как у вас) и `python` смог спокойно взаимодействовать с ней. Мне кажется проблема в том, что вы неправильно вызываете скрипт с консоли. Вы пишите `todo\manage.pyrunserver`, но наверно вам нужно: `todo\manage.py runserver` (`runserver` это аргумент запуска, а не часть расширения файла)